# Text::CSV - open with encoding - blank_is_undef

Tags: perl, csv

Why does the empty field not result in an undefined value when I add an encoding format to the open mode?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = 'TEST.csv';
open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
print $fh 'hello,,world';
close $fh;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( {
    sep_char             => ',',
    auto_diag            => 1,
    blank_is_undef       => 1,
    binary               => 1,
} );

open $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
my $tmp;
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
    push @$tmp, $row;
}
close $fh;
print Dumper $tmp;

#$VAR1 = [
#          [
#            'hello',
#            undef,
#            'world'
#          ]
#        ];

open $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file or die $!;
$tmp = [];
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
    push @$tmp, $row;
}
close $fh;
print Dumper $tmp;

#$VAR1 = [
#          [
#            'hello',
#            '',
#            'world'
#          ]
#        ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in [`Text::CSV_PP`](http://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV_PP) ([`Text::CSV_XS`](http://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV_XS) doesn't display this symptom)

The problem is that, if the line read from the file is flagged as being UTF-8-encoded, then each field split using the separator character is passed through `utf8::encode` even if it has previously been set to `undef` because the field is blank and the `blank_is_undef` option is enabled. That incorrectly sets it back to an empty string

You can explicitly use `Text::CSV_XS` instead, or there is an undocumented option `decode_utf8` which can be set to false along with the other options in the `Text::CSV` object, or if you need to process UTF-8 properly then you should use [`Text::CSV::Encoded`](http://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV::Encoded)

Comment: I thought that `Text::CSV_XS` was installed but it wasn't. Now with `Text::CSV_XS` installed it works fine.